# How to correctly implement rich domain model with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am trying to change my objects to Rich domain models. My original class, before trying to replace it with rich domain model, was like this:

```
public class StudentLogic : IStudentLogic
{
    private IUnitOfWork _uow;
    private IStudentRepository _studentRepository;

    public StudentLogic(IUnitOfWork uow, 
        IStudentRepository studentRepository)
    {
        _uow = uow;
        _studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }

    public int CreateStudent(IStudent newStudent)
    {
        return _studentRepository.Create(newStudent);
    }
}
```

With IStudent declared as:

```
public interface IStudent
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

So now I try to convert to Rich domain model.

A student cannot exist without FirstName and LastName, so based on what I read about Rich domain model, this should be included in the constructor. My rich domain model for student would look like this:

```
public class Student : IStudent
{
    public Student(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int Create()
    {
        return _studentRepository.Create(this);
    }
}
```

How do I inject the UoW and Repository? It seems awkward to put it in the constructor along with the firstName and lastName. And is the pattern I'm following generally correct?

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that the `Create` method really belongs to the `Student` class. You shouldn't force your self to create a rich domain model. If some behavior belongs to the entity itself then it should be there. If it doesn't belong there then you shouldn't force it to be there even if that means that sometimes you end up with an "anemic" model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Check that interfaces can't declare members with accessibility modifiers like `public` and they can't define *fields* but properties, events, methods...</strike> **I've fixed this issue in your question editing it...**

In the other hand, a *rich domain model* woudn't create a persisted *domain object* and the method representing the whole creation wouldn't be returning an *integer* but the created domain object.

About *dependency injection*, in C# and depending on the inversion of control container, you can either inject dependencies using *constructor dependencies* or *property dependencies*.

The whole point of using construction-time dependencies is that they're mandatory. If your domain object can't work without a repository and unit of work implementations, you'll want to require them in your domain objects' constructors. Otherwise, if some of the dependencies is *optional*, you can inject it using *property injection*:

```
public class Some 
{
    // Mandatory, because a non-optional constructor parameter
    // must be provided or C# compiler will cry
    public Some(IUnitOfWork uow) { ... }

    // Optional, because you may or may not set a property
    public IRepository<...> Repo { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, setting properties during construction-time isn't the requirement of a domain to be *rich*. What makes a domain model *not anemic* is that domain objects aren't just *data storage* but they provide *behavior*.

Comment: "setting properties during construction-time isn't the requirement of a domain to be rich" - I am aware of this, but I read that I should put in constructor properties that are required (object shouldn't exist w/o these properties). If this is correct, my constructor will include: firstName, LastName, repository, and UoW (assuming repository and UoW are required). Is that ok?

Comment: @g_b You shouldn't take patterns as dogmas. Adapt them to your concrete domain and even take your own architecture decisions. Usually, a domain objects without a parameterless constructor is a bad idea if you need to map them to an underlying database like when you use an OR/M.

Comment: @g_b Also, there's a lot of discussion about the convenience of a full rich domain model, and even if *anemic domain model* is an anti-pattern at all.  I believe that you should find a balance between both concepts. Now don't move any behavior from a service layer to your domain models. This would be implementing *active record* design pattern rather than *rich domain model*.